# How can I display 30 pages of text in a (scrolling) screen

Tags: react-native

I want to display 30 pages of text on a screen. I've tried `ScrollView` and `FlatList` but I get a white screen. Only when I try with `ScrollView` to display only 2 pages, works fine.

I do not want to use a `WebView`, because I would like to have all data in the app (no internet connection needed).

Here is what I've already tried:

With `FlatList`:
I have a `text.js` as a `model`, which I use to create a `Text` Object in an array, which I then use as `data` for the `FlatList`. For the `renderItem` function (of FlatList) I use a `TextItem` to display the text.

text.js

```
function Text(info) {
    this.id = info.id; 
    this.text = info.text;
}
export default Text;
```

LongTextModule.js

```
import Text from '../../models/text';

export const LONGTEXT = [
    new Text({
        id:'text_1',
        text:`.....longtext....`
})
]
```

TextItem.js

```
const TextItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.screen} >
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{props.longText}</Text>
        </View >
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    textStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        fontFamily: 'GFSNeohellenic-Regular',
        fontSize: 20,
        padding: 10,
    }
});
```

TextDetailScreen.js

```
const TextDetailScreen = (props) => {
    const renderText = data => {
        return <TextItem longText={data.item.text} />
    }

    return <FlatList 
            data={LONGTEXT} 
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id} 
            renderItem={renderText}
            />
};
```

I think it's needless to show the code with ScrollView, since ScrollView is only for a small list.

I even tried to render the longText like this in the screen.
Without the ScrollView I get the first portion, but with ScrollView a white screen.

```
const TextDetailScreen = (props) => {
    return (
        <ScrollView>

            <Text> ...longText...</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};
```

I'm sure there is a way to display a lot of pages of text on a screen?
But how?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not to be an unknown Issue, I've also read from time to time about this issue.

But not to use Webview, because you wan't to have all Data in your app - ***don't have to be*** an Argument against Webview. With WebView, you also can display Data from your App-Storage.

**Example:**

```
<WebView style={styles.myStyle} source={{html: `<p style="font-size:48px">${longtext}</p>`}} />
```

Comment: Hi @suther. Thanks a lot for the help! It's working fine with `WebView` as you suggested. I came across it..., but I show only the `uri` version... Anyway, thanks again. Happy coding :)

Comment: You're Welcome! Happy that it helps you out.